Spark 3.0 Cannot write non-nullable data to iceberg
I have an avro file which has a field called timeStamp which is a mandatory field without any default value. Which means there is no chance to get this field as null. The schema defined as below
    {"name": "timestamp","type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"}}

I have an iceberg table where this timestamp column is a partition and its defined as NOT NULL column
timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (days(_timestamp))

When i am writing data to this table using spark . it throws the below exception even if my source avro data doesnt have null values
Cannot write nullable values to non-null column 'timestamp'

I tried multiple options such as

Adding .config("spark.sql.iceberg.check-nullability", "false") in spark config -> doesnt work
Tried custom schema mapping to make timestamp as non-nullable inside spark -> not working still spark reading it as nullable

Somehow with all these option spark read the timestamp field as nullable and thats causing the problem . How can make spark to understand that its a non-nullable field apart from the above solutions which i have tried
I am using the spark 3.3.0 and Iceberg 1.2.0 versions
This is how i am writing this data to iceberg using partition overide
    spark.read()
        .format("avro")
        .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
        .load(getS3aPath())
        .writeTo(getTableNameWithDB())
        .overwritePartitions();

Thanks in Advance

Found the answer myself ;) posting it so that it might help others
This behavior is by design . Spark does read all the fields as nullbale even if you defined it as mandatory fields in avro. You have to do the below things
Schema Inference and RDD Conversion: Spark reads the Avro data and infers a schema from the files. When you convert the DataFrame to an RDD and back to a DataFrame using myStructType, you enforce the desired schema, ensuring the timestamp field follows your specified nullability rules.
Code looks like below
   StructType yourStucktType = getYourStucktType();
    Dataset<Row> avroDataSet = spark.read()
        .format("avro")
        .load(Path());
    Dataset<Row> convertedDataSet = spark.createDataFrame(avroDataSet.rdd(),
        yourStucktType); --> this does the magic :) 
    convertedDataSet.writeTo(getTableName())
        .overwritePartitions();

